# Как быстро добавить вариации для woocommerce товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется три параметра, в которых по 10 вариаций.
Как мне задать цену для каждой вариации, чтобы он сам считал, сколько какая вариация стоит?

Comment: В каком смысле "как"? Каждой вариации цена и так задаётся.

Comment: Каждую вариацию надо руками прописывать.
А если есть, допустим: пиццы, напитки и соусы.
Вот как сделать чтобы к пиццам можно было попутно выбрать соусы и напитки?

Comment: Это не вариативный, а составной товар если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: Но ведь на составной товар нельзя указывать цену на основной товар, и указывать что можно добавлять по 1 товару из составных, поэтому это более вариативный, нет?

Comment: Вариативный - это когда разные ВАРИАЦИИ - цвет напр, или размер. А если нужен выбор КОМПЛЕКТАЦИИ (из отдельных товаров по разным ценам) - это составной.

Comment: А вообще да, наверное в данном случае всё же вариативный нужен. В составном по умолчанию выбор *кол-ва* каждого товара, а не выбор самих "комплектующих". Хотя в нек случаях и этот вариант может подойти.

Comment: А как поступить в данном случае? Что посоветуете? проставлять цену для каждой вариаци - убийство. Пытался Chained Products подключить - в форме поиска пишет Product not found, когда пытаюсь подключить его к вариации.

Comment: К сож не подскажу. :(  Точно помню, что видел решение (плагин), но это было давно. Вчера искал долго (самому интересно стало), но так и не нашел. Если попадётся что - маякну.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Пробовал TM Global Extra Product Options. Опции добавляет, а вот при добавлении в корзину - добавляет только базовую цену без опций. Не знаю уже что делать.